# Not using the certificate for a certain request in Postman

Tags: postman

Is there a way to set up one request to use a provided certificate and another request to not use any certificate at all in Postman?

Comment: Certificate and authorization both are different thing. Certificate is used to secure the connection. Authorization is used to validate user on a sever. Certificate settings can be found from Settings > general settings. Your requirement is bit unclear.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for the info. My question is if it is possible setup one request to use a certificate and another request to not use any certificate.

Comment: Not sure if that is possible.